# 3D Problem in Photoshop: Model becomes a hole in a Rectangular Prism

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

Every time I try to create a custom shape using the pen and turn it into 3D, it becomes a "hole" in a rectangular prism instead of being the inverse.

I am an amateur so pardon if the question is stupid.

How do I solve this?

[image]

Expected output is below:
[image]

Comment: For what it's worth: [Find answers to frequently asked questions around discontinued 3D features in Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/3d-faq.html)

Comment: @user287001 I have added the image above.